# Even Without Internet the link shows the image

Tags: html, hyperlink

I created a html file (mytest.html)that has bellow tag

```
<a href="https://pointsprizes-blog.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/485.jpg"> 
go to this link please</a>
```

I ran this link (https://pointsprizes-blog.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/485.jpg) in my browser first to see if it is a correct link,
then I ran this file(mytest.html) in my pc & when I click the link "go to this link please" in the file, it showed the image.

I tried this without internet connection and it still showed the image correctly.
Then I restarted the PC & ran the file and clicked the link (without internet connection) it still shows the file.
My problem is how did my link shows the image without internet if it points to a website ?

I even searched the download folder for such a image file(485.jpg).Did not find such a file.

Comment: this image can be cache in your browser, try clearing the cache in your browser and it should not appear anymore.

Comment: Note you're not actually "running" anything, you're loading an HTML file in a browser.  If you want to force reload without the cache, you can do SHIFT-CTRL-R or SHIFT-CMD-R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browsing history and cache. Turn off your internet connection and try again. It will give you error.

You need internet connection to load that image. Once you load image it will save in cache. Second time you try to load image and if you already saved in cache. It will load from cache.

Answer (score -1):

Basically this question is based on the concept of browser cookies.

> Cookies, more properly called HTTP cookies, are small bits of data
>   stored as text files on a browser. Websites use those small bits of
>   data to keep track of users and enable user-specific features

When you run your .html file with the internet connection ON, the data gets stored into your [browser cookies](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/cookies-guide/)

Now even if you switch off your internet connection the data is already stored in the web browser

Try Deleting the cookies from your web browser and run the html file again, you would get an error message